# Send vector<int> through serial in json format

Tags: c++, json

For json parsing i use 
https://github.com/nlohmann/json

My code:

```
...
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "json.hpp"    
using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // read a JSON file
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::ifstream i("filee.json");
    json j_complete = json::parse(i);
    std::vector < int > data_send_to_LED;
    for (int i =0; i<j_complete["tablica"].size(); i++){
        data_send_to_LED.push_back(j_complete["tablica"][i].get<int>());
    }
    for (int i =0; i<data_send_to_LED.size(); i++){
        cout <<"data send: "<< data_send_to_LED[i]<<endl;
    }
    json j_vec(data_send_to_LED);
    int* pv = &data_send_to_LED[0];
    ...
    n = write(sockfd,pv, data_send_to_LED.size());
 }
```

How can i send vector data_send_to_LED as json through serial?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all details of your code

```
json j_vec(data_send_to_LED); // this makes the json text?
int* pv = &data_send_to_LED[0]; // hope you don't do anything with data_send_to_LED after this point.
...
n = write(sockfd,pv, data_send_to_LED.size()); // this sends the data as binary
```

What you might need to do is get a pointer the data in j_vec, could be j_vec.data(), and the size might be j_vec.size().

```
n = write(sockfd, j_vec.data(), j_vec.size());
```

The size might need to be +1 to get a zero terminate over.

Comment: I add something like this json j_vec(data_send_to_LED);
  auto pv = j_vec.get_ptr<json::number_integer_t*>(); but still i can't get pointer. I get error "Bad address"?